# swift setting string from array element error

Tags: arrays, core-data, swift

So im grabbing a property from core data, using a dictionary. And it grabs it just fine. However, when I try to take that single returned attribute and assign it to the navigationitem.title it throws some nasty error. Am I missing something here..
Its not actually outputting an error message in the console but instead is giving me this:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code+exc_I386_BPT.....
```

on this line.

```
0x10707a5f3:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

Also its saying

```
0 swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional
```

code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let frequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Round")



    frequest.propertiesToFetch = NSArray(object: "course")
    frequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    frequest.returnsDistinctResults = true

    frequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.DictionaryResultType



    var fetchedArray = context.executeFetchRequest(frequest, error: nil)

    //this is the line that throw the error...why won't it let me set the title to the array of the single returned result?
    self.navigationItem.title = fetchedArray[0]

    println(fetchedArray)

}
```

Comment: "some nasty error"? What's the error, specifically? The contents of that error are probably an excellent clue.

Comment: Provide the specific error message you're getting so we can help you, please.

Answer (score 0):

Without a specific error message you are receiving, this is just a guess...

`NSArray` un untyped contents (that is to say that elements are of type `AnyObject`), so the compiler probably doesn't think you can set `AyObject` as a string. So likely need something like:

```
self.navigationItem.title = fetchedArray[0] as String
```

Or:

```
self.navigationItem.title = String(fetchedArray[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

To start, I would check couple of things to see if the problem is in the fetched array or in the navigation item:

1. what exactly is returned in fetchedArray[0]? Is is a string? A nil? Something else? Does it actually have anything at index 0? After checking if fetchedArray is not nil and has any elements, you could use "\(fetchedArray[0])"
2. What is the state of navigationItem? Is it actually instantiated at the time you are trying to set it's title property? I would suggest checking it for nil. You can also try assigning it a string like this: self.navigationItem.title = "Hello" and see if it fails.